# Slow and crashing Windows Explorer. Hard drive or virus?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, windows-explorer, crash

I have a custom built machine with windows 7 ultimate.

- Core2Duo 2.93Ghz
- 12GB RAM
- 500GB Hdd
- Nvidia GTX 650 Ti Boost 2GB

Everything was running fine till a few days ago when Windows Explorer started crashing and hanging up the system.

When it happens some other programs sometimes also hang and crash too. Also I can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> during its fits, it just comes up with a black screen. I can get the Task Manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> but then that hangs sometimes.

If I manage to get explorer.exe to end, I often can't get a run window open for at least a minute to open explorer.exe. Even when it comes up it hangs and I end up hard reseting the computer. It seems to happen randomly and the CPU is <15 percent. I've done some research and it might be a HDD issue.

HDTune reports 11 bad sectors, I don't know how bad that is though. On another note, I've yet to run Malwarebytes. But Vipre Antivirus reports no viruses. I'm not quite sure whats up!

Also, if it could be related, I have been having a problem putting/waking from sleep. It says I get a BSOD (which I never actually see) that has error code 9f. Any suggestions, or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Follow the instructions from the following URL and upload your minidumps, so we'll try to analyze them and figure what's causing these issues:
http://www.0xpanic.com/#!guide1/cdpa

Comment: @HDTune - This is very likely caused by the bad sectors.  I encountered this problem shortly before total kernel panics, which caused BSODs, that were unable to create a memory dump.  My problem would be a problem for a few minutes then go away, then come back, then go away.  But the inability to view task manager and the unresponsive applications are classic system disk failures.

Comment: Here's the minidump. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22865035/100913-28189-01.dmp Malwarebytes detected nothing. I'm going to run Hiren's Boot CD and check again.

Comment: Also, this is what HDTune is giving me. http://i.imgur.com/05x5nlU.png http://i.imgur.com/dkOkyz2.png

Answer (score 1):

Well... the minidump won't say much.
As for the HDTune bench results: they aren't optimal for that drive, but nothing that will put that drive as the main culprit here.

I have 2 possible suggestions that might solve your problems:

1) Run MEMTEST86+ for a couple of hours for each of the memory sticks you have SEPARATELY.
 * If these issues occur frequently - you can just unplug one of the sticks and see if the problems still persists (if it is - try the same method with the other stick, on a different slot)

2) Try the system file checker:
Open up the command prompt as an administrator then run:
sfc /scannow

By the way - Please specify the exact model of your power supply (you can write a comment to this post)

**EDIT**

Jadar just follow this URL and update the Broadcom drivers:
http://wikidrivers.com/wiki/Broadcom_BCM43xx_win6x

Comment: the dump is very helpful. The very old broadcom driver is causing the crash,

Comment: Oops... my bad.
you're right.
I've no idea how I couldn't see "bcmwl664.sys"

Anyway, I'll edit my post for a relevant solution.
Thanks @magicandre1981 !

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a ACPI issue in the BIOS. Check drivers on the video and use Windows Update. Review the event log for the time frame you mentioned and go from there.

Comment: What am I looking for? Windows is fully up-to-date. Just ran it a day or two ago.

Comment: Ya, I don't see any errors in Windows Logs -> System that would relate to hard drive/ACPI problems. Just that the system was unexpectedly turned off. There is one error, though. Event 8003. I don't think that has anything to do with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

The dump shows that Broadcom driver (bcmwl664.sys) causing the crash:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: fffffa800a0dc060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff80000b9c4d8, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: fffffa800e6809f0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt!KiProcessTimerDpcTable
nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList
nt!KiTimerExpiration
nt!KiRetireDpcList
nt!KiIdleLoop

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x9f_3_power_down_bcmwl664_image_pci.sys


>[ 16, 2]   0  0 fffffa800b33a050 00000000 00000000-00000000    
          Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\bcmwl664.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for bcmwl664.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for bcmwl664.sys
 \Driver\BCM43XX
            Args: 00015400 00000000 00000005 00000003
 [ 16, 2]   0 e1 fffffa800b1aa040 00000000 fffff80002f11200-fffffa800e8dae00 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\vwifibus nt!PopSystemIrpCompletion



  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_4329&SUBSYS_7D001385&REV_01\4&278ccf74&0&08F0"
  ServiceName is "BCM43XX"


    Loaded symbol image file: bcmwl664.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\bcmwl664.sys
    Image name: bcmwl664.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Mar 27 02:06:57 2009
```

So update the driver:

http://www.devdrivers.ru/load/broadcom_wireless_lan_drivers/broadcom_wifi_802_11n_802_11ac_network_adapter_drivers_v_6_30_95_48_6_31_95_1_drajvera_dlja_setevykh_adapterov_wifi_802_11/37-1-0-1613

Comment: I'll try that! I do think it also has something to do with the nVidia update I did.